# Magento 1.7 Append Complex Data

Tags: magento

I am trying to append a category id to a large number of SKUs in Magento 1.7. I have used the Import > Append Complex Data and, although it checked the file and ran ok, it did not add these SKUs to the category I wanted them in.

So, the objective is to leave all these SKUs in the categories there are in now but add an additional category.

Any help would be appreciated. Even if it is a different method entirely.

Answer (score 0):

The fastest way to do this is to directly insert this as a SQL query using:

```
INSERT INTO `catalog_category_product` (
`category_id` ,
`product_id` ,
`position`
)
VALUES (
'4', '34', '0'
), (
'4', '35', '0'
);
```

In this case, it would add the category Id of 4 to the products with Id 34 and 35. You can create a small PHP script to dynamically create such a query from your file of SKUs and Category Ids.
Reindex after your query was successfully executed.

Alternatively, using the Magento eco-system and not the database, you can do this:

```
$categoryIds = array();
$toBeUpdatedProducts = array(4,6,7); // all the Ids you want to update
$newCategoryId = 65; // Id of new category
foreach ($toBeUpdatedProducts as $productId) {
    $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($productId);
    $categoryIds = $product->getCategoryIds();
    $categoryIds[] = $newCategoryId; // Add new category to existing ones
    $product->setCategoryIds($categoryIds);
    $product->save();
}
```

Comment: Manipulating data via direct SQL scripts is always a bad idea when you have a good ORM system with CRUD provided (which is the case with Magento).

Comment: @JernejGolja I disagree, at least with the word always. Usually, it is a bad idea. However, in some cases, the overhead of the whole ORM system when you handle large amounts of data can be devastating for the speed of simple actions.

Comment: @JernejGolja Added the non-database way for completeness

Comment: Thanks for the comments @mpaepper. I was trying to work out what the Import > Append Complex Data could do? Anyone have knowledge of this feature?